# Table inside figure environment

Tags: tables, errors, minipage

I want two tables in the same line. I insert them using a `figure` environment and then minipages, inside each minipage I include one table.

The trouble is that it doesn't allow me to include the caption on my table.

Here my code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}{0.5\columnwidth}
\begin{table}
        \caption{Datos medidos para $L_1$.}
        \label{1L1}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            n&  $S_o$ [cm]&     $S_i$ [cm]&     $y_i$ [cm]\\
            &  $\pm0.05$ cm& $\pm0.05$ cm& $\pm0.05$ cm\\
            \hline
            1&  10.0&   56.7&   17.8\\
            \hline
            2&  12.0&   36.7&   10.7\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}
.....
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

It shows me the error: `Not outer in par mode \caption`

If I retire `\begin{table}`,`\end{table}`, it compiles good but the caption says Figure #. And I want it to be Table #......

Answer (score 5):

Don't nest `table` environments inside another floating environments (such as a `figure` environment). Instead, use a single `table` environment to encase two `minipage` environments, each containing a `tabular` environment plus `\caption` and `\label` directives.

Furthermore, do consider giving the tables a more open look, say by omitting all vertical bars and reducing the number of horizontal bars.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\small
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
        \caption{Datos medidos para $L_1$.}
        \label{1L1}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l ccc@{}}
            \toprule
            n&  $S_o$ [cm]&     $S_i$ [cm]&     $y_i$ [cm]\\
            &  $\pm0.05$ cm& $\pm0.05$ cm& $\pm0.05$ cm\\
            \midrule
            1&  10.0&   56.7&   17.8\\
            2&  12.0&   36.7&   10.7\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\hfill % maximize space between the minipages
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
        \caption{Datos medidos para $L_2$.}
        \label{2L2}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l ccc@{}}
            \toprule
            n&  $S_o$ [cm]&     $S_i$ [cm]&     $y_i$ [cm]\\
            &  $\pm0.05$ cm& $\pm0.05$ cm& $\pm0.05$ cm\\
            \midrule
            1&  10.0&   56.7&   17.8\\
            2&  12.0&   36.7&   10.7\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like @Mico, I'd use `booktabs`, and `floatrow`, which is done to place floats side by side, and has a better spacing between caption and table than the default. I also use `makecell`, to group the first two rows, since they're semantically linked. This results in a shortercode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs, floatrow, makecell}
\floatsetup{floatrowsep=qquad}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \small\centering
  \begin{floatrow}
    \ttabbox{ \caption{Datos medidos para $L_1$.} \label{1L1}}
    {\begin{tabular}{@{}l ccc@{}}
      \toprule
      \thead{n}& \thead{ $S_o$ [cm]\\ $\pm0.05$ cm}& \thead{$S_i$ [cm]\\ $\pm0.05$ cm}& \thead{$y_i$ [cm]\\ $\pm0.05$ cm}\\
      \midrule
      1& 10.0& 56.7& 17.8\\
      2& 12.0& 36.7& 10.7\\
      \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}}
    \ttabbox{ \caption{Datos medidos para $L_2$.} \label{2L2}}
    {\begin{tabular}{@{}l ccc@{}}
      \toprule
      \thead{n}& \thead{ $S_o$ [cm]\\ $\pm0.05$ cm}& \thead{$S_i$ [cm]\\ $\pm0.05$ cm}& \thead{$y_i$ [cm]\\ $\pm0.05$ cm}\\
      \midrule
      1& 10.0& 56.7& 17.8\\
      2& 12.0& 36.7& 10.7\\
      \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}}
  \end{floatrow}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess, the problem is, that you want to use a `floating` environment in an other `floating` environment (table in figure). If you remove the `\begin{table}`...`\end{table}` it solves the error, but the `\caption{}` will be the part of the `figure`.
The cheap solution for your problem is the renaming the string "Figure" to "Table":

`\renewcommand{\figurename}{Table}`

The only weak point that this "false table labels" will be considered as figure labels (in the list of figures, in the list of tables ect...).

If you want do this trick once in the document, you have to restore the `\figurename` with storing it.

Here is my full code for it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\let\OldFigurename\figurename       %% store the original 'Figure'
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Table}   %% overwrite 'Figure' with 'Table'

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}{0.5\columnwidth}
        \caption{Datos medidos para $L_1$.}
        \label{1L1}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            n&  $S_o$ [cm]&     $S_i$ [cm]&     $y_i$ [cm]\\
            &  $\pm0.05$ cm& $\pm0.05$ cm& $\pm0.05$ cm\\
            \hline
            1&  10.0&   56.7&   17.8\\
            \hline
            2&  12.0&   36.7&   10.7\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\columnwidth}
        \caption{Datos medidos para $L_1$.}
        \label{1L1}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            n&  $S_o$ [cm]&     $S_i$ [cm]&     $y_i$ [cm]\\
            &  $\pm0.05$ cm& $\pm0.05$ cm& $\pm0.05$ cm\\
            \hline
            1&  10.0&   56.7&   17.8\\
            \hline
            2&  12.0&   36.7&   10.7\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{\OldFigurename}  %% restore 'Figure'

\begin{figure}
        \caption{Datos medidos para $L_1$.}
        \label{1L1}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            n&  $S_o$ [cm]&     $S_i$ [cm]&     $y_i$ [cm]\\
            &  $\pm0.05$ cm& $\pm0.05$ cm& $\pm0.05$ cm\\
            \hline
            1&  10.0&   56.7&   17.8\\
            \hline
            2&  12.0&   36.7&   10.7\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more straightforward to use a `table` environment instead of renaming `\figurename` twice?

Comment: This does not work, you have renamed the figure to table but it will be kept in sequence with figures not tables.

Comment: Yes the best solution is using `table` instead of `figure`; but if the questioner wants to use `figure`...

Comment: No the questioner was confused and the answer is supposed to make the document better not maintain the main error.  The code above will make tables be printed out of sequence in a real document that has more tables.